# How to allow &nbsp with wp_kses()?

Tags: escaping, wp-kses

I have an html containing &nbsp but I am unable to pass it through wp_kses(). I have tried adding allowed html `array('&nbsp' => array(),)` but does not seems to work. 
I there a way or I should not do that?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300142/how-to-add-extra-whitespace-in-php/23844752

Comment: Did you use `&nbsp` or `&nbsp;` ? And what's the exact `wp_kses()` code you used?

Comment: @SallyCJ not sure the difference but i used `&nbsp` for adding a white space ..then passed it through wp_kses()

Comment: `&nbsp;` is the correct one - the `;` is required. Otherwise, that's an invalid HTML entity and `&nbsp` would result in `&amp;nbsp`.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you! worked.

Comment: You're welcome. And be sure to use valid HTML entities. :) (You can check some [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))

Comment: @SallyCJ I totally missed it..strangely it was working fine before I used wp_kses(); I believe it was doing &amp;nbsp as you said.  I will be happy to mark it as an answer though the question is out of topic now:). Please drop it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> not sure the difference but I used `&nbsp` for adding a white space
>   ..then passed it through `wp_kses()`

The correct HTML [entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) for a non-breaking space is `&nbsp;` — note the `;` which is required and *without it* (i.e. `&nbsp`), the entity is not valid and when used with `wp_kses()`, you'd get `&amp;nbsp` instead of a non-breaking space.

> strangely it was working fine before I used `wp_kses()`

I'm pretty sure it's because the browser is smart enough and auto-corrected it to `&nbsp;`. :-)

So, ***always*** use valid HTML entities and also tags (e.g. close a `<div>` with a `</div>`), regardless you use `wp_kses()` or not. Don't rely on "intelligent guess" or auto correction by the browser.